# Why am I getting such a large alignment memory requirement for an image?

Tags: vulkan

I create an image in Vulkan and I get an alignment requirement in the memory requirements of 131072. This seems like an enormous alignment and I'm not sure why anything bigger than 128 or 256 may be needed. It's so big that my memory allocation algorithm can't even handle it, and will never be able to practically handle it given that each allocation of this strict an alignment will waste too much space. What's the deal behind this? Here is how I create the image:

```
VkImageCreateInfo create_info{};
create_info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
create_info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
create_info.pNext = nullptr;
create_info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
create_info.samples = VkSampleCountFlagBits::VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
create_info.queueFamilyIndexCount = 0;

image_create_info.extent.width = 1716;
image_create_info.extent.height = 1731;
image_create_info.extent.depth = 1;
image_create_info.usage = VkImageUsageFlagBits::VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT;
image_create_info.tiling = VkImageTiling::VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
image_create_info.initialLayout = VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
image_create_info.flags = 0;
image_create_info.mipLevels = 1;
image_create_info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT;
image_create_info.arrayLayers = 1;

VkImage vk_image;
VkResult result = vkCreateImage((VkDevice)VK::logicalDevice, &image_create_info, nullptr, &vk_image);

VkMemoryRequirements requirements;
vkGetImageMemoryRequirements(VK::logicalDevice, vk_image, &requirements);
```

Another interesting thing about the requirements returned by the function is that the memory size requirement for format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT is about 12 mb, which makes sense, but with a format of VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UINT (so without the alpha channel), it gives a size requirement of only 3 mb, about a quarter of the size. Have I run into some sort of bug?

I know the dimensions of the image I created aren't power of two, but surely this shouldn't lead to such strange behaviour, should it?

Comment: It would only be considered "strange behavior" if the alignment were different if you tried to allocate a 2048x2048 image.

Comment: "*with a format of VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UINT (so without the alpha channel), it gives a size requirement of only 3 mb*" I want to see proof of that. 1716*1731*3bpp=8'911'188. It's literally impossible to store an image of that size, in that format, in 3MB. You must be doing something else different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's so big that my memory allocation algorithm can't even handle it and will never be able to practically handle it given that each allocation of this strict an alignment will waste too much space.

Then fix *that*.

Implementations are allowed to require all kinds of alignments, *especially* for optimally-tiled images. 128KiB alignment is hardly unreasonable for images. So your sub-allocator needs to be able to account for this.

As for "waste too much space," perhaps you should take another look at those numbers. The example texture must take up at least 11'881'584 bytes. 128KiB is slightly more than 1% of that storage. That's not a lot of waste.